# ADF set null value to input field

Tags: java, oracle-adf, business-process-management

I am trying to set value to binding that correspond to af:inputText.
But after validation phase pop up message is showing up with text:
  Error
 For input string:""

Here tr .jspx sample:

```
...

<af:commandButton text="Запрос" id="cb1"
                                actionListener="#{taskServiceBean.requestArticle}"/>
...

<af:inputText value="#{bindings.periodExpireInit.inputValue}"
                                label="New perion:"
                                required="false"
                                columns="#{bindings.periodExpireInit.hints.displayWidth}"
                                maximumLength="#{bindings.periodExpireInit.hints.precision}"
                                shortDesc="#{bindings.periodExpireInit.hints.tooltip}"
                                id="it2"
                                partialTriggers="cb1">

</af:inputText>
...
```

Backing bean sample (TaskServiceBean):

```
public void requestArticle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
   initFeald();
   clearAll();
   ....
}
private void clearAll() {
   artPeriodExpireInitBinding = (AttributeBinding) bindings.getControlBinding(PropertyHolder.BPM_ART_PERIOD_EXPIRE_INIT_BINDING);
   artPeriodExpireInitBinding.setInputValue(null);
}
```

*periodExpireInit* is int variable in bpm process that passed in adf form through humman task/

Comment: When is this `clearAll()` method called?

Comment: It is called from the action listener on click of the button.

Comment: Seems like your error message is because it is not accepting null values. Is there a condition for this input field to not accept null values? Could you post the entire stack error message?